# How to dynamically change icon name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

so i have this code:

```
                                      <Icon
                                            onPress={async () => {
                                                if (favorites.some(item => item == post.id)) {
                                                    favorites.splice(favorites.indexOf(post.id), 1)
                                                    const newFavoritesArrayWithoutClickedID = favorites
                                                    await AsyncStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(newFavoritesArrayWithoutClickedID))
                                                } else {
                                                    const newFavoritesArray = [...favorites, post.id]
                                                    await AsyncStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(newFavoritesArray))
                                                }
                                            }}
                                            name={favorites.some(item => item == post.id) ? "heart" : "heart-outline"}
                                            type='ionicon'
                                            color={Colors.primaryRed}
                                        />
```

But if i press the heart icon it will add to async storage and show it in favorites but the heart icon doesnt change untill next render. Is there any solution to change this icon dynamically?

UPDATE:

Here i declare FAVORITES state, fetch it from Async Storage and fet it to favorites

```
   const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            let response = await AsyncStorage.getItem("favorites");
            response = JSON.parse(response)
            response !== null && !favorites.includes(...response) && setFavorites([...favorites, ...response])
            response = ""
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])
```

Comment: is it necessary to use local storage? you can change the icon dynamically without using local storage (only using ```useState``` hook). but it's okay if your architecture needs local storage

Comment: call setFavorites in onPress callback,and save to AsyncStorage in useEffect hook

Comment: Hello, @JabalLogian, yes it needs the local storage since i want to store the favorite posts in there and i dont want to send them to my website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set state `favorites` state in `onPress` function. I would suggest ot modify your code in this way:

```
<Icon
   onPress={async () => {
      if (favorites.some(item => item == post.id)) {
        const newFavoritesArrayWithoutClickedID = [...favorites];                                      
        newFavoritesArrayWithoutClickedID.splice(newFavoritesArrayWithoutClickedID.indexOf(post.id), 1);
        setFavorites(newFavoritesArrayWithoutClickedID); //<-- set new state
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(newFavoritesArrayWithoutClickedID));
      } else {
        let newFavoritesArray = [...favorites];
        newFavoritesArray = [...newFavoritesArray , post.id];
        setFavorites(newFavoritesArray); //<-- set new state
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(newFavoritesArray));
      }
   }}
   name={favorites.some(item => item == post.id) ? "heart" : "heart-outline"}
   type='ionicon'
   color={Colors.primaryRed}
/>
```

Explanation: when you work with React, if you want to dynamic re-render something you have to use state variable. Your initial `useEffect` sets `favourites` the first time but if you change it on some logic (like `onPress` function) you should update state value if you want to re-render the icon.

Comment: Happy to ear that. Have a nice coding =)